# Make first array element key and second value in php flat array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am working on a project where I have to sum score for some tags. The idea is to make the array even values key and odd values as values  I did search on google but I fail to create a structure like below. I need the array structure like below this way I can easily sum the values with the same key.

```
$array = array("22" => 3, "27" => 2, "30" => 1, so on...) from the below array.


[0] => 22
[1] => 3
[2] => 27
[3] => 2
[4] => 30
[5] => 1
[6] => 22
[7] => 3
[8] => 25
[9] => 2
[10] => 28
[11] => 1

The code I am using to map the array with key-value pair according to the above logic.

$rank = $_POST['ranking_details'];
$rinfo = explode('_', $rank);

$result = array_map(function($v){
    return [$v[0] => $v[1]];
}, $rinfo);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [3] => 0
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Code:

```
$arr = array(22, 3, 22, 3, 27, 2, 22, 3, 30, 1);
$dic = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
    if (array_key_exists($arr[$i], $dic)) {
        $dic[$arr[$i]] = $dic[$arr[$i]] + $arr[$i + 1];
    } else {
        $dic[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i + 1];
    }
}
print_r($dic);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [22] => 9
    [27] => 2
    [30] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I sum key 22 and values 3+3 = 6

Comment: If the 22 is 3 times in array with values 3+3+3 = 9?

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas, Try the edited solution on top. It accounts for cases with multiple keys (3+3+3 = 9)